# Why do I need to report to the Spanish embassy after return to my home country?

Tags: schengen, spain, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a Schengen visa for the first time along with my family from the Spanish embassy. We were given visas successfully. However, they stamped a note only on my passport (probably because I am sponsoring my family?) that says:

> Please report back to the Spanish embassy or consulates upon your return to Pakistan before 25-08-2017. Failing to do this would result in rejection of subsequent visa applications.

What is the purpose of this? Do they want to check whether the main destination of stay and first point of entry was "Spain" itself, as stated in my application?

Comment: They most likely want to ensure that you did in fact leave the Schengen Area. This is because entry and exits into the Schengen Area are not recorded.

Comment: @RodneyHawkins aren't the Schengen exit controls supposed to verify that and issue a ban if necessary?

Comment: @JonathanReez Sure, but I was thinking from an enforcement position, as in knowing who to investigate and look for inside the Schengen Area. I'm just speculating here. There could be a valid reason. If anybody knows, please write an answer. It's certainly interesting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an enforcement measure practiced in countries with high level of visa violations.

In some cases, embassies/consulates of many EU countries even ask applicants for a pledge, e.g. national ID card to ensure they'll come back to their homeland.

Comment: Don't they have entry or exit records? What difference would it make anyway even if the person does not return?

Comment: As Rodney has stated above, this is more an enforcement measure - to increase chances you'll not violate terms of your visa. It also makes it harder to "cheat" by using different passports, etc.

Comment: @AsadMoeen No, at the moment they rely on the passport stamps. This will probably change at the end of 2021 when enter and exit will be recorded.